# get mean of certain elements in a vector

Tags: matlab, mean

I have a vector **X** which is a 20x1 double. I would like to calculate the mean for the 4 elements `X(7,1), X(8,1), X(10,1)`, and `X(12,1)`. One way to do this is:

```
M=mean([X(7,1), X(8,1), X(10,1),X(12,1)])
```

However, typing out all the elements is very inefficient, especially if I want to find the mean for even more elements. Is there a quicker way to write this? This seems to be a very easy operation but I have not been able to find the answer. I would appreciate a solution a direction to a post elsewhere. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mean(X([7,8,10,12],1))`

You can request a subset of indices by indexing with a vector instead of a single number.